# Duplicated filter emails again

Tags: bug, email-notification, tag-filters

Before marking this as duplicated, I did find a couple of questions with the same question, but they were back in 2012 and were marked as solved.

I've been getting multiple emails for my tags subscriptions:

[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442638/get-message-by-id-discord-js) is the question on that email.

And this is the emails list:

[image]

I've also yesterday received a notification on my email for another question, but it was just one email. I also went to check if I had any duplicated subscriptions, and [nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvTlf.png).

### What I did

1. Find a tag you want subscribe
2. Hover the tag
3. Click Subscribe
4. Accept it on your email
5. Change the check time to 15 minutes
6. Wait

Comment: Same problem here. I get duplicates about 50 minutes apart - often after I have already answered the question! For me this started happening about 6 months ago; I get about 2-5 duplicates per day.